# Auto-forward an email using Linux

Tags: linux

Is there a way thatour Linux Server can auto-forward an email based on some certain rules. More likely the function of settings rules in Outlook....?

Answer (score 2):

Most MDAs have their own configuration file which can be used to specify delivery options such as forwarding rules. See the procmail [mini-FAQ](http://www.iki.fi/era/procmail/mini-faq.html) if your server is using `procmail`.

Comment: ...or it can be done on the MTA